# How can I log the value of the input field to the console whenever it changes

Tags: angularjs, logging, input

I'm experimenting with the angularjs phonecat tutorial ([I'm at step 5](https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.7/docs/tutorial/step_05)) to better understand how angular works. But I fail to manage to log the value of the input field to the console. I tried different approaches, but none of them are working.

How can I access the $ctrl.query variable, and log it whenever it changes? Do I use $watch?

I hope somebody can show me how it is done and maybe explain in detail why and how it is working.

Comment: Use the [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I seem to have found a solution. I added this to the controller of the phoneList component.[image: loggin input]

Learning Angular is really not that easy ^^.

Comment: Don't answer with pictures of code. It makes it difficult to read and impossible to copy and paste.